# get current url of the page (used URL Rewrite)

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am working on classic asp application.
I have use URL rewrite on some pages.

How can i get current url of the page in classic asp?

Example: 
http://www.site.com/page.asp ---> url rewrite in IIS ---> http://www.site.com/home/page

so here i want current url of the page which is http://www.site.com/home/page

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you read it with `Request.ServerVariables("server_name") & Request.ServerVariables("url")` ? Not sure if this works with rewritten urls too...

Comment: no Request.ServerVariables("server_name") = www.site.com and Request.ServerVariables("url") = page.asp

Comment: Could you please mark any of these answers if they were helpful for you? If not please let us know so that we can find the solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try to output all ServerVariables like so:

```
for each key in Request.Servervariables
  Response.Write key & " = " & Request.Servervariables(key) & "<br>"
next
```

Maybe the URL you seek is already there. We use the Rewrite module and there is a ServerVariable called `HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL` that contains the rewritten URL path, e.g. "/home/page" in your example.

Protocol (`HTTPS=ON/OFF`) and Server (`SERVER_NAME`) can also be found in the ServerVariables.

Answer (score 21):

There's no fancy one function that does it all.

First you need to get the protocol (if it is not always http):

```
Dim protocol
Dim domainName
Dim fileName
Dim queryString
Dim url

protocol = "http" 
If lcase(request.ServerVariables("HTTPS"))<> "off" Then 
   protocol = "https" 
End If
```

Now the rest with optional query string:

```
domainName= Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") 
fileName= Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") 
queryString= Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")

url = protocol & "://" & domainName & fileName
If Len(queryString)<>0 Then
   url = url & "?" & queryString
End If
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you use URL Rewrite, the url data can only be retrieved in this way:

**Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL")**

Example

```
Dim domainName, urlParam
domainName = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") 
urlParam   = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL")
response.write(domainName & urlParam)
```

Comment: Thank you. Saved me a lot of database work. Now, the URL is set for every page in the meta tag. Love it.