# Classic ASP - get full url name

Tags: asp-classic

Im wondering if someone could help me.

I have the following URL ( which is dynamic )

```
www.website.com/images/gal/boxes-pic004.asp
```

How can i extract the 'boxes-pic004' part using classic ASP

Thanks

Comment: Possible [duplicate #1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15395280/2662901), [duplicate #2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8600266/2662901)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<%
Dim sScriptLocation, sScriptName, iScriptLength, iLastSlash

sScriptLocation = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
iLastSlash      = InStrRev(sScriptLocation, "/")
iScriptLength   = Len(sScriptLocation)
sScriptName     = Right(sScriptLocation, iScriptLength - iLastSlash)
%>
```

`sScriptName` will then contain `boxes-pic004.asp`, then you can use `Replace(sScriptName, ".asp", "")` to remove the extension as well.

Answer (score 8):

Just you can try to output all **ServerVariables** like,

**Eg Page Url:** https://www.google.com/gmail/inbox.asp?uid=1421&skyid=2823595

```
Dim strProtocol
Dim strDomain
Dim strPath
Dim strQueryString
Dim strFullUrl

If lcase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")) = "on" Then 
    strProtocol = "https" 
Else
    strProtocol = "http" 
End If

strDomain= Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
strPath= Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") 
strQueryString= Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")

strFullUrl = strProtocol & "://" & strDomain & strPath
If Len(strQueryString) > 0 Then
   strFullUrl = strFullUrl & "?" & strQueryString
End If

Response.Write "Domain : " & strDomain & "</br>"
Response.Write "Path : " & strPath & "</br>"
Response.Write "QueryString : " & strQueryString & "</br>"
Response.Write "FullUrl : " & strFullUrl & "</br>"
```

**Output:**

```
Domain : www.google.com
Path : /gmail/inbox.asp
QueryString : uid=1421&skyid=2823595
FullUrl : https://www.google.com/gmail/inbox.asp?uid=1421&skyid=2823595
```

Comment: downvoted as it does not answer the question about extracting the 'boxes-pic004' part

Answer (score 2):

Simple

Just use `Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")` and then do some string chopping to get the stuff you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would depend on the method you used to do the URL rewriting.

1. Using IIS - Refer to this previous post on how to extract the full URL: [get current url of the page (used URL Rewrite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395280/get-current-url-of-the-page-used-url-rewrite)
2. Using 404 - This is how I've done it in the past and the only way to access the raw URL is to check the querystring. The 404 URL will look something like this:

   ```
   https://website.com/rewrite.asp?404;http://website.com/images/gal/boxes-pic004.asp
   ```

To get the URL, I use something like this:

```
    Function getURL()
        Dim sTemp
        sTemp = Request.Querystring
        ' the next line removes the HTTP status code that IIS sends, in the form "404;" or "403;" or whatever, depending on the captured error
        sTemp = Right(sTemp, len(sTemp) - 4)
        ' the next two lines remove both types of server names that IIS includes in the querystring
        sTemp = replace(sTemp, "http://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & ":80/", "")
        sTemp = replace(sTemp, "http://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & "/", "")
        sTemp = replace(sTemp, "https://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & "/", "")
        sTemp = replace(sTemp, "https://" & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") & ":443/", "")
        ' the next bit of code will force our array to have at least 1 element
        getURL = sTemp
    End Function
```

This will get you the full raw URL, you can then extract the part you need by using simple split like:

```
    tmpArr = Split(getURL(),"/")
    strScriptName = tmpArr(UBound(tmpArr))
```

The strScriptName variable will then return "boxes-pic004.asp".

Hope this helps.