# Getting current page on HTML

Tags: html, syntax, boolean

I am a beginner HTML and I am having trouble putting my idea into the right syntax.
I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<div id="footerterms"><span class="mainsmaller"><a href="/privacy.jsp">Privacy</a> | <a href="/terms_of_use.pdf">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="/sitemap.jsp">Site Map</a></span></div>
```

What I am trying to do is to have them open in a new tab whenever the user is on a specific page.
I figured that having a `boolean` is a fair way to do it. I wrote the code below, but it seems that the syntax is off.

```
<var showIt=true;>
<% showIt = Request.ServerVariables("URL") == "payment.jsp" %>
    <% if(showIt){ %>
        <div id="footerterms"><span class="mainsmaller"><a href="/privacy.jsp" target="_blank" >Privacy</a> | <a href="/terms_of_use.pdf" target="_blank" >Terms of Use</a> | <a href="/sitemap.jsp" target="_blank" >Site Map</a></span></div>
    <% }else{ %>    
        <div id="footerterms"><span class="mainsmaller"><a href="/privacy.jsp">Privacy</a> | <a href="/terms_of_use.pdf">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="/sitemap.jsp">Site Map</a></span></div>
    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also wrap '}' in an ASP block and declare the variable properly. 
About the URL check, you can read [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632131/classic-asp-get-full-url-name#18632335).

```
<% showIt = Request.ServerVariables("URL") == "theUrlToCheck" %>
<% if(showIt){ %>
    <div ...>...</div>
<% }else{ %>    
    <div ...>...</div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I edited my question with your suggestion. It looks like it is still crashing when I run it.